# Rails URL Problem on HOST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have problem on my rails hosts, when i want to show a models.
i get this error

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.

We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly.
```

in my localhost i have no error, but in the server that doesn't works.
Here is my url.

my show models route are like

```
/users/:id
```

I think its because of the id, but i really dont kno

have you any idea how to resolv this?

I'm hosted with Site5 on clouad server

thanks.

Comment: Check the logs from your host and it will tell you what exception caused this error.  Have you migrated your database?

Comment: There's no error in the log file..  i checked all log file and ro error on it. and yes i have migred the db.

Answer (score 0):

Check the production.log. The error is explained in details there. For sure.

Comment: hmm yeah i never check in rails log just on server log, wow sorry for that.. but the error say server can't find a column in the DB, i checked with phpmyadmin, and the column name are exacly the same, but i have decloppez with rails 3.0.9 and the server run with 3.0.1 i have do some change to work on the server, but that can cause that? i use find_by_user_id_and_owner(params[:id], true) but i dont know if its supported with rails 3.0.1? i think yes. But what can cause this problem? i don't know, It's work really fine on my localhost.